# Spring: Use @Qualifier()-qualified bean if available, otherwise use any

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a component that will accept a bean (`fasterxml` `ObjectMapper`) to be specific.

If there is a qualified bean named `qualifiedObjectMapper`, I want to use that bean.

If there isn't a bean with that name, but there is an `ObjectMapper` bean at all, I want to use that.

As far as I know, if I do this:

```
class MyClass(
  @Qualified("qualifiedObjectMapper") objectMapper: ObjectMapper
)
```

It will only work if there is a bean with that name, but won't use another `ObjectMapper` bean if there isn't (if there are multiple, use the primary).

Is there a way to use the qualified if it exists, otherwise use the primary?

Comment: Do you have access to mark the `qualifiedObjectMapper` as primary, using either XML (`primary="true"`) or Java annotation `@Primary`?

Comment: Potentially, but in this case, it might not necessarily be the primary. It might be a secondary that is only used for this and the primary is used throughout the app otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For doing this you can use `@Configuration` class, where you create another qualified bean based on primary and optional ones:

```
@Configuration
class Config {
    @Primary @Bean
    ObjectMapper primary() {...}

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper qualified(){...}

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper resulted(ObjectMapper primary, 
                         @Autowired(required = false)  @Qualifier("qualified") ObjectMapper qualified){
       return qualified == null ? primary : qualified;
    }
}
```

And use that resulted bean as:

```
@Service
class MyService {
    MyService(@Qualifier("resulted") ObjectMapper mapper) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    @Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

and then

```
    try {
    ObjectMapper obj = applicationContext.getBean("qualifiedObjectMapper");
    //use qualifier
}catch(Exception e) {
    //use objectMapper
}
```

Comment: I'd really rather not use `applicationContext.getBean("")`. While it'd technically work, there are lots of downsides to using it. (Though note, I'm not the one that downvoted... it's not what I'm looking for, but it's not a bad idea.)